# Best practise - Struts2 / Spring Integrated application startup process - for adding default lookup values in application context

Tags: spring, struts2, initialization, applicationcontext

I am a Struts2 and Spring newbie and looking for some insight. When we load a web application we would typically want to cache some default look up data. e.g. if we wanted to store states or other data that does not change frequently and add it to the application context where we can access it across the application. What is the best way to realize this in a Struts2 application integrated with Spring? I read a bit about annotating with @PostConstruct which means I define my own class/method that would get a handle to the context by calling ServletActionContext.getServletContext() and then use setAttribute to add something. Is that a good way of going about things or is there a better option? Or would simply implementing a ServletContextListener be ideal?

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `ServletContext`, use Spring's `ServletContextAware` interface and then use an `@PostConstruct` or `afterPropertiesSet` method to add items to the servlet context.

This is simpler to use than the listener and integrates seamlessly with Spring, giving you access to properties files declared in Spring and any other beans.